# how to fix drafty window

Tags: weatherstripping, draft

Please check out attached picture of corner of my double hung window. I feel cold air there during winter time when it is too much windy. Can anyone tell me which area of window requires weatheratripping and what kind of ?

[image: drafty window]

Comment: that area needs caulk, not stripping, which is used where flat mechanical parts interface.